# Kolmogorov complexity of sequence and its fragment

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity

Is it possible that part of sequence is more complex than all sequence because the best way to encode it is to use the complete sequence **and** starting and ending positions of the fragment.

Maybe, for example, string of hexadecimal digits of $\pi$. Or something else.

Comment: If both sequences are intended to be infinite, then any added 'starting point' complexity will be drowned out in the long run.  If both are finite then I believe there can be a logarithmic gap.  And if one is finite and one is infinite, how are you comparing them?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I would say yes, however, only by $O(|n|)$ (the length of program/TM that would truncate such sequence including the desired length of output sequence). An example of such sequence might be some prefixes of output of [Busy Beavers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver). Still, this is just my intuition.

I hope it helps ;-)